# Nginx reverse proxy can't forward request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a simple config:

```
http {
    server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name mynginx.local;
    
    location /prom {
        auth_basic "Access to Prometheus server";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpassw;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.192:9090/;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

and with this config don't work after i entering username and password, and in the log i see this:

```
*10 open() "/etc/nginx/html/graph" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.3, server: mynginx.local, request: "GET /graph HTTP/1.1", host: "mynginx.local:8081"
```

but! if i change in the config file this line location /prom to this one location /  - all works fine properly!

can anyone asks me why?

Comment: Looks like after the login you get redirected to `/graph`, and that one URI doesn't fall under the `location /prom { ... }` thus being served via `$document_root/graph` file/directory (your default `root` is `/etc/nginx/html`).

Comment: as i know in the nginx config for reverse proxy don't need set document_root path, or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, for the requests that are going to be proxied nginx config doesn't need a root. But the `/graph` URI is not going to be proxied since it doesn't match the `location /prom { ... }`. You still didn't understand what happened? When you change your location to `location / { ... }` that URI (returned from your upstream via redirect, as I understand) is going to be proxied. My English isn't perfect but I thought my explanation was quite clear. Unless you made your upstream to return every URI prefixed with `/prom` that kind of configuration won't work.

Comment: Maybe the [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive can help you.

Comment: Unfortanetly, proxy_redirect didn't help me, in many resources the right config of reverse proxy looks like on my config... i still have a problem.

Comment: remove the last slash from the port 9090 instead of 9090/